# Where do I put and how to use Table() calls in a project with SQLAlchemy Core and flask?

Tags: python, sqlalchemy, flask-sqlalchemy

So I want to use SQLAlchemy Core and flask in an application. I have read through the documentation and a lot of tutorials how to structure your application. All of the SQLAlchemy Core tutorials put the Database description directly into the app.py file of the application. I'd like to put this Database description into its own python module (called tables/ here) and usw it in my views, forms etc. So I want to achieve a basic layout like the following:

```
myapp/
    run.py
    tables/
        __init__.py
        tables1.py
        tables2.py
        ...
    views/
        views1.py
        ...
    ...
```

What I struggle especially with is the following:

1. Should I put `metadata = MetaData()` into  `tables/__init__.py` and import it in the `tables/__init__.py` files?
2. Am I supposed to simply import the instances from the `tables/tablesX.py` files if I want to access my Tables?
3. The perfect solution for me would be to put all the tables into the metadata object. If I then need access to a table in e.g. a view I could simply pull the table out of the metadata with `table = meta.tables[table_name]`. But I have no clue how to pass the metadata object around so that it holds all the tables.
4. Or am I completly on the wrong path here and am I supposed to create the table description (i.e. call `table = Table(name, tmp_metadata,...)` directly in my views.py files?

Thank you for your time and best wishes,

A.H.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let's do it one step at a time. Minimal application:

```
from sqlalchemy import ...
from flask import ...
from flask.ext.sqlalchemy import ...

app = Flask()
db = SQLAlchemy()

class Foo(db.Model):
    ...

@app.route(...)
def foo():
    Foo.query.filter(...)
    return ...
```

Let's move the db stuff out into a separate module:

```
# db.py
from sqlalchemy import ...
from flask.ext.sqlalchemy import ...

from .app import app

db = SQLAlchemy(app)

class Foo(db.Model):
    ...

# app.py
from flask import ...

from .db import Foo

app = Flask()

@app.route(...)
def foo():
    Foo.query.filter(...)
    return ...
```

But wait, we have a circular dependency, so we have to move `app` out:

```
# app.py
from flask import *

app = Flask()

# db.py
from sqlalchemy import ...
from flask.ext.sqlalchemy import ...

from .app import app

db = SQLAlchemy(app)

class Foo(db.Model):
    ...

# views.py
from flask import ...

from .db import Foo
from .app import app

@app.route(...)
def foo():
    Foo.query.filter(...)
    return ...
```

Next, we can split `db.py`:

```
# app.py same

# views.py same

# db/__init__.py
from flask.ext.sqlalchemy import ...

from ..app import app
from .foo import Foo

db = SQLAlchemy(app)

# db/foo.py
from sqlalchemy import ...
from . import db

class Foo(db.Model):
    ...
```

But wait, we have a circular dependency again, so we have to move `db` out:

```
# app.py same

# views.py same

# db/__init__.py
from .common import db
from .foo import Foo

# db/common.py
from flask.ext.sqlalchemy import ...

from ..app import app

db = SQLAlchemy(app)

# db/foo.py
from sqlalchemy import ...
from .common import db

class Foo(db.Model):
    ...
```

SQLAlchemy Core configuration is exactly the same, except replace `class Foo` with your `foo_table = Table(...)` declarations.

Comment: _SQLAlchemy Core configuration is exactly the same, except replace class Foo with your foo_table = Table(...) declarations._ This is exactly what confuses me. So in order to use my tables I need to import the foo_table instance? Is there a way to only import the metadata object that holds all the tables or do I need to import the instances (as the Table() call is after the metadata creation)?

Comment: @AHoover The metadata object is available at `db.metadata`, so you can just import `db`.

Comment: Yes, but as `metadata=Metadata()` needs to be called before `foo_table=Table(..., metadata, ...)` the metadata object won't include the tables unless the table instances are imported before the metadata object. So I guess the answer is that I should import the table instances if I want to access the tables?

Comment: @AHoover `db = SQLAlchemy(app)` initializes the metadata. It is guaranteed to execute before your table declarations because we import `db` from `foo.py`, and we are guaranteed to import your table declarations because we import from `.foo` in `db/__init__.py`.

Comment: Sorry, I am a bit confused here. So what you are saying is that if I put `from sqlalchemy import Metadata` and `metadata=Metadata()` into `common.py`, `from .common import metadata` and `from .foo import foo_table` (where `foo_table=Table(...)` in `foo.py`), then I can simply do `from .db import metadata` and the `metadata` object will then hold all my table definitions like `foo_table`? And alternatively I can import my tables with `from .db import foo_table`? If that is so, I can gladly accept your answer!

Comment: @AHoover `from .common import metadata` and `from .foo import foo_table` go in `__init__.py` (you missed this part), but yes. This is a viable alternative if you don't want to use flask-sqlalchemy (but there's no reason to not use flask-sqlachemy).

Comment: And I forogot: `db.metadata` corresponds to the metadata object usually created by `metadata = Metadata()` in pure SQLAlchemy right?

Comment: @universio Just to be clear and eleminate the rest of my confusion: With 'but yes' you mean that I could them import `metadata` in my views and it would hold all my tables or alternatively can import the table instances directly?

Comment: Sorry for the confusion and thank you very much once more! I can't really express how thankful I am!